# NSURLSession and Multithreading

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, grand-central-dispatch, nsurlsession

I just want to clarify something although it seems fairly straightforward from what I've read so far in Apple's documentation.
When `NSURLSession` comes into play, by default, any tasks are set to run on separate threads. So when I write

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
[[session downloadTaskWithRequest:request] resume];
```

the downloading process (delegate methods, completion handlers e.t.c.) runs on a queue (i.e. thread) other than the main one. So there is for instance no need to create an `NSOperationQueue` myself or put the "resume" call inside a `GCD` block (e.g. `dispatch_async()`).

Have I understood correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, everything runs in background thread by default and you can also inspect that at runtime if you wish.

Answer (score 4):

I guess the below link will answer your query where a brief information about NSURLSession is given where they mention "No NSOperation sub-classing necessary". Also you do not need to specify what queue you are running on. Unless you specify otherwise, the calls will be made on a background thread.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/51127/nsurlsession-tutorial

Regards,
Anil

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if the session has to be run on Main Thread, it can be done by :-

```
[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:sender delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
```